# how to create api key to android Google Cloud Messaging for Android

Tags: android

I want to use Google's cloud messaging for android in my application
So I'm going to https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae
And I'm starting to do step by step
I was able to perform all the steps except one.
Could not create key
I'm going to Google's Developer Console -> my application -> Api & auth -> Certificates
And I want to click on Create a new key but the button is not enabled on the image above
http://i250.photobucket.com/albums/gg253/gallavie/Untitled_zps82778fdd.png
Why can not I click on create a new key?
thank you

Comment: try to create first new project and then create key

Comment: but I have project why I need to create new project